Metal pushbutton voltage drops only to 3.15V when OFF
I'm trying to detect a press of a 5-terminal LED button using the tutorial here: https://newbiely.com/tutorials/esp8266/esp8266-button-long-press-short-press
Works with no issue with standard pushbutton (4 legs, wired to ground and input IN pin), however, it doesn't work with 5 terminal self-resetting halo button. I did notice that when I pressed the button the voltage drops only to ~3.15V instead of 0V. Do you know why that might be caused?

Thanks!

In all the codes in that tutorial the digital pin is configured as INPUT_PULLUP, so the internal pullup resistor will pull it to 3.3V.
Since you connected to pin to NC (normally connected), the button is connected to 3.3V when not pressed, and to nothing when pressed - and in that case the pullup resistor pulls it towards 3.3V. Depending on your supply and your measurement method that might be a bit lower (like your 3.15V), though comfortably inside the HIGH range.
Either connect the common pin (C) to ground, or use INPUT_PULLDOWN (if your board supports that) or an external pulldown resistor (from the digital pin to ground, value like 1kOhm should be good)

Thank you @chrisl, connecting common to the ground and switching the signal to NC worked like a charm :)
